# React - update component class on custom Scroll change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today I'm looking for a React solution to communicate between two components and to update HTML classes within TableComponent when the scroll changes.

ScrollComponent:

```
export class ScrollComponent {
   onScrollMove(){
      ...
   }

   render(){

   }
   ...
}
```

TableComponent:

```
export class TableComponent {
   ...

   render() {
      return <div className="table">...</div><ScrollComponent/>
      // ScrollComponent is a child here to move table content
   }
}
```

My question is what should I use to check inside TableComponent whether ScrollComponent has changed its position and at the same time to add table class into something like table-scroll-moved.

What is the solution, concept, idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, however I will try to help you based on the information you have provided. One method to achieve what you are asking is to pass a method from TableComponent to ScrollComponent via the child's props. That could look something like:

```
export class TableComponent {
   ...

   scrollPositionHasChanged = () => {
      // do something
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="table">...</div>
         <ScrollComponent
            scrollPositionHasChanged={ this.scrollPositionHasChanged }
         />
   }
}
```

Then in the ScrollComponent you would call scrollPositionHasChanged in the onScrollMove function like so:

```
export class ScrollComponent {
   onScrollMove(){
      this.props.scrollPositionHasChanged();
   }

   render(){

   }
   ...
}
```

However, I like to send all of my "actions" in a single object for readability. This is not necessary, but it helps keep things clean when you are passing lots of props to a child component. So something like:

```
<ScrollComponent
   actions={{ onChange: this.scrollPositionHasChanged }}
/>
```

Then in ScrollComponent you would call this.props.actions.onChange. It is longer to type but clarifies that anything within the actions object is a callable method.